# Rufus killed USB card reader

Tags: windows-8.1, usb, bootable-media, micro-sd-card, card-reader

This was really odd, I haven't found anything like this on the web.

I tried to create a bootable microSD card with PNY microSD USB card reader using Rufus 2.2. It was set to check the device for bad blocks. After maybe 30 minutes Rufus stopped midway saying that there are around ~230 bad blocks. Everything of course stopped. Since that any computer "does not feel" at all my PNY card reader.

I checked the card is OK but the card reader with any card on any PC does not show up in any place. Is there any hope to revive it?

Comment: You should change your title, Rufus didn't "kill" anything. You're USB simply deteriorated over time, it's how they fundamentally work. You're card **reader** doesn't have sectors. "does not feel" is extremely vague and not at all an accurate description. What do you mean by "any" computer? 1,2,3? Have you ever used the card reader in those other computers before? Could be a driver issue. What have you done to determine it has to be the card? Have you even tried a different SD? What do you mean by "doesn't show up any place?" Have you checked `diskmgmt.msc`, `diskpart` or just "My Computer?"

Comment: Well, the USB did not just deteriorate, it stopped working right after I run Rufus. The card reader also has a flashing light but it does not light up since then. I checked this on 4 PCs, on 3 of them everything worked before and drivers were not a problem. I tried other microSDs too. The microSD card is fine, but the card reader is not working anymore neither on other PCs nor on Ubuntu nor it shows up in diskmgmt.msc. Though I don't know how to work with diskpart in cmd.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the USB deteriorating, I was talking about the microSD, those things **do** happen. Rufus didn't do anything, it's mere coincidence. If you've diagnosed that the Micro is still good and that it's firmly the Adapter, well then you have your answer. No you can't 'revive' it. Even if you could it wouldn't be worth the effort. The adapter went bad and not a result of Rufus. Did you plug it into a USB 3.0 port?

Comment: I tried both USB 2.0 and 3.0. It was in USB 3.0 port when it happened.

Comment: You may also want to read [this](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_Rufus_damaged_my_flash_drive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Card readers, USB dongle's, etc.. **can** all go bad. Especially depending on the type and/or quality. In my own experience, microSD card to USB adapters, by far, are the most finicky. I've gone through three different microSD to USB adapters over the years and countless dongles. It's a good thing they are not too expensive.

Again however, Rufus didn't kill anything. It's simply coincidence that the dongle was going bad and Rufus detected errors because it couldn't read the card. To answer your question. **No**. Based on your description of symptoms there is not a way to 'revive' it.

Unless on the off chance something burned out (I've had dongles burn out and *pop* after being plugged into USB 3.0) and you're into Micro soldering. In which case you would already be doing rather than posting here or better yet, realize that it wouldn't be worth it.